# Is It Possible to Satisfy Everyone?

Tags: algorithm, graph, logic, nodes, matching

You are given two sets of nodes, each with the same number of nodes. Set A contains a list of people. Set B contains a list of items. Each person has a preference for any number of items in Set B. If we represent these preferences as connections between the person nodes and item nodes, each node must have at least one connection.

Initially I thought that each person can always get their desired item, but this is not always true, for example something like this may happen:

[image]

One thought I had was that as long as there are (set A size + set B size-1) or more connections in the graph, it's always possible to form valid connections. However, I'm having troubles proving the correctness of this. 
Do you know if this is correct? Or is there a different solution completely?

Comment: FYI, I've rolled back your edit, firstly because it invalidated an existing answer, and secondly because the updated version didn't explain the goal precisely enough for the question to be answerable.

Comment: In general, no.  https://www.kalimaquotes.com/images/quotes/EN/36008-IranianProverbs-Quotes-EN.jpg

Comment: Hall's marriage theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem) gives necessary and sufficient conditions for a solution to exist.

Comment: If you have 100 people, and 99 items, and everyone likes every item, then you obviously have no solution, but 9900 connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this problem the following way:

- Sort people of A by the number of edges they have (from lower to higher).
- If a person in A has only one prefered item in B, assign it.
- When a person in A has more than one prefered item in B, choose the item with the smallest number of people in A that prefer it.

I'd do this with backtracking.

Comment: If you take the case where there's N+1 people and N items that everyone likes, then your algorithm will try N! combinations before failing.

Comment: Not really. The item that not everyone likes would be the prefered to be chosen (step 3) and the others would just choose any item of the N itens left. In fact, this might be solved in one iteration only.

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid your theory is not correct. Imagine set A has 10 people and set B has 10 items. Your theory says that 19 connections are needed. But in fact, you could have many more without having a solution.

For example, split the sets into groups of 7 and 3. Then connect every person in the group of 7 people to every item in the group of 7 items. That's 49 connections.

And the two groups of 3 could still be connected as shown in the question. Thus, with 10 people and 10 items, you could have 53 connections without having a solution.

---

Thanks to [@PaulHankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400793/paul-hankin) for pointing out [Hall's marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem#Graph_theoretic_formulation) in the comments.

I will paraphrase the theorem here. The proof is in the linked article.

> Given two sets A and B of equal size, a saturating matching is a
>   matching that covers every element of both sets.
>
> For a subset {b} of B, let {a} denote the subset of A that has
>   connections to {b}.  The marriage theorem states that A and B have
>   a saturating matching if and only if for every subset b of B:
>
> |b| <= |a|
>
> In other words: every subset of B has sufficiently many connections
>   to A.

Let's apply this to the graph in the question.

[image]

We see that the subset b={b1, b3} in B is connected to the subset a={a2} in A. We note that |b|==2 and |a|==1, so the condition |b| <= |a| is not satisfied, and the graph does not have a saturating matching.

To use Hall's marriage theorem as the basis for an algorithm to verify the existence of a saturating matching, we would need to check every subset of B. How many subsets are there? The set of all subsets of B is known as the [powerset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of B. The powerset contains 2^n subsets of B (where n is the number of elements in B). So using the theorem directly results in an O(2^n) algorithm.

Algorithms that solve the [maximal matching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Algorithms_and_computational_complexity) or the [balanced assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem#Balanced_assignment) can be used to solve this problem more efficiently.